# Bootstrap dropdown menu hiding behind Silverlight application embedded using iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, silverlight, iframe

If anybody come across below issue “bootstrap dropdown menu hiding behind silverlight application embedded using iframe”, please let me know.

We have tried with below properties with iframe and application but no luck.

1. Z-index
2. Position
3. Float
4. Overflow

If you clearly observe below error image, dropdown menu displaying in  between iframe and Silverlight application, it means application is just laying on iframe not inside of iframe.

Issue mainly causing by the Silverlight control is created by Microsoft code dynamically and it’s using a Windowless parameter set to false.  This means that HTML controls more often than not dive behind the Silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to abandon your boostrap menu. Instead create a menu that goes into another IFRAME and put that IFRAME over the Silverlight IFRAME.